# How to define a double-key shortcut?

Tags: c#, wpf, shortcut

One can define a shortcut in WPF with

```
<KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Control" Command="local:CustomCommands.MyCommand"/>
```

Shortcut `CTRL + N` is now defined.

**Question:** Is it also possible to define a double-key shortcut like Visual Studio 2012 uses it?

**Example:** `CTRL + R, A` is used to execute all unit tests.

Comment: I originally missed the point that you need multiple keys, not modifiers. This can be done, but not easily. [Here is an article](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/03/multikeygesture.html) that will walk you through it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Gesture in conjunction with Key instead of modifier. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When defining a KeyBinding in Extensible Application Markup Language
>   (XAML) there are two ways to specify the KeyGesture. The first way to
>   establish a KeyBinding in XAML is to **define the Gesture attribute of
>   the KeyBinding element, which enables a syntax to specify keys and
>   modifiers as a single string, for example "CTRL+P"**. The second way is
>   to define the Key attribute and the Modifiers attributes of the
>   KeyBinding element.

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Control+R" Key="A"
            Command="local:CustomCommands.MyCommand"/>
```

This will execute `MyCommand` in case `Ctrl+R,A` combination is used.

Comment: Are you sure this works only for that exact sequence? From the same MSDN page: "You can potentially have situations where for example a Key set last will overwrite just the Key component of a preceding Gesture but leave the Gesture's modifiers the same."